# How to send image to Google Form via API by axios or ajax request?

Tags: axios, google-forms

i try to capture a snapshot via video + canvas html5 elements and send the capture image to my Google Forms form. in the form i have an simple value and a file upload (in my example images) option.

how can i sent the capture screen shot to the Google Forms API?
- if some one have example with axios it will be great!

Thank,
Chen.R